# Performance issue with Pandas merge function

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging multiple CSV files by using Pandas' merge function but it takes more than 3 hours to process. Note that I have more than 1K files to merge and columns can be different even though "SECURITY" column is common in each file and values of it are unique. Any tips to increase the performance? I am probably doing something wrong or inefficient. Thank you very much!

```
def consolidate_data_files (file_names, thread_count):
output_file_names = [] 
joined_frame = None
file_count = 0
for file in file_names:
    data_frame = pandas.read_csv(str(file), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dtype=str)
    if file_count == 0:
        joined_frame = data_frame
    else:
        joined_frame = data_frame.merge(joined_frame, how='outer')
    file_count += 1
total_row_count = len(joined_frame.index) 
row_per_file = math.ceil(total_row_count/thread_count)
merged_file_count = int(math.ceil(total_row_count/row_per_file); 
for i in range(merged_file_count):
    file = "merged_file_"+str(i)+".csv"
    output_file_names.append(file)
    row_start = int(i * row_per_file)
    row_end = int(row_start + row_per_file)
    joined_frame[row_start:row_end].to_csv(path_or_buf=file, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
del joined_frame
return output_file_names
```

Comment: Have you timed how long each section takes? That's the first part with trying to optimise things.
Other thing I can think of is you might want to use "SECURITY" as the index, and then you won't need to merge but you can just add in the new columns

Comment: Also if you know how many rows/columns you have in advance you could create a dataframe with nan values first, and then fill it in. I imagine each merge requires creating a new section of memory and copying the existing dataframes, which is slow

Comment: Thanks Jezzamon! I did what you suggested and it looks like merging each file takes longer than previous one and this seems to be the main issue. Instead of merging all files to one, I am pushing joined_frame into an array and then re-create it and continue merging. Currently testing the new method hope it works.

Comment: it worked like a charm! overall merge time decreased from more than 3 hours to only a few minutes. also, i used append instead of merge which seems to be faster.

Comment: @data_guy so what was your implemented solution?